# Round values while preserving the sum WITH specific intervals

Tags: r, math, rounding

I want to round a vector of values WHILE preserving the sum AND taking into account an interval number.

Let´s say I have a vector:

```
vector <- c(0.2, 1.8, 40.4, 10.6, 0.5, 1.5)
```

Now I want to round the numbers while preserving their sum of 55. This function does just that:

```
smart.round <- function(x) {
   y <- floor(x)
   indices <- tail(order(x-y), round(sum(x)) - sum(y))
   y[indices] <- y[indices] + 1
   y
}
```

> smart.round(vector)
>   [1]  0  2 40 11  0  2

BUT I want to also take into account an interval that an user has defined. Let´s say 5. This function does just that:

```
mround <- function(x,base){ 
   base*round(x/base) 
}
```

> mround(vector, 5)
>   [1]  0  0 40 10  0  0

Now I want to combine both functions. But I cant figure out how. Basically I would like the output to be:

```
vector <- c(0.2, 1.8, 40.4, 10.6, 0.5, 1.5)
```

> combined.round(vector, 5)
>   [1]  0  5 40 10  0  0

(as 1.8 is closest to 5 and atleast one value needs to be rounded to 5 to preserve the sum of 55) 
Sum is 55 and every number has interval of 5 in the required output.

Any help or suggestions are much appreciated!

Comment: why does 1.8 get rounded down to 0 while 1.5 gets rounded up to 5?

Comment: My bad, it should be 1.8 ofcourse. Have edited it.

Comment: 1.8 is closer to 0 than to 5 so why round up? I guess I mean why not round up 0.2? In general what is rounded up and what is rounded down?

Comment: Because I need to preserve the sum. To preserve the sum in this case requires one of the values to round up to 5. 1.8 is closest to 5.

Comment: Doesn't dividing by 5, applying your `smart.round` function, and then multiplying by 5 do what you want?

Comment: That indeed works. Here's the complete function then: 
combined.round <- function(x, interval) {
  x <- x / interval
  y <- floor(x)
  indices <- tail(order(x-y), round(sum(x)) - sum(y))
  y[indices] <- y[indices] + 1
  y * interval
} 

If you answer the question with that function I can upvote it for other people.

Answer (score 1):

I am not the one who found the solution but I guess somebody has to post it for everyone. It's a beautiful solution, thanks! [@Miff](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3379675/miff)

```
smart.round <- function(x, interval = 1){ 
  x <- x / interval 
  y <- floor(x) 
  indices <- tail(order(x-y), round(sum(x)) - sum(y)) 
  y[indices] <- y[indices] + 1 
  return(y * interval)
}
```